# Java : Failing to connect to mySql DB

Tags: java, mysql, sql, exception, connection

I just set up a local mySql database. I can connect to it properly through command line and third party software (Navicat..).

Server:    `localhost:3306`

User:       `root`

Password:  `password`

Database name: `students`

However, when I try to connect with java, I get an error.

**CODE:**

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class Sql {

   public static void main(String[] args) {

    Connection conn = null;

    try {

        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

        conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306//students?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false",
                "root", "password");

        Statement sqlState = conn.createStatement();


    } catch (SQLException ex) {

        System.out.println("SQLException" + ex.getMessage());
        System.out.println("SQLException" + ex.getSQLState());

    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

   }

}
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
SQLExceptionCould not create connection to database server. Attempted reconnect 3 times. Giving up.
SQLException08001
```

**Also tried:**

```
conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306//students", "root", "password");
```

and

```
conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306//students?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false","root", "password");
```

**Additional Attempts:**

The firewall is disabled.

I installed the Jconnector by putting the .bin.jar in:

*C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_73\jre\lib\ext*

I can see it on the left under JRE in Eclipse and the import doesn't give errors.

**NOTEs:**

Using mySQL from the terminal, workbench or Navicat gives no errors, any query works, the local server is running properly and the credentials are *correct*, the user has full admin priviledges.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you able to login through MySQL console or workbench

Comment: Yes I am, as I wrote in the beginning.

Comment: shoudn't it `localhost:3306/students` ? not sure

Comment: Try changing your mysql connector jar

Comment: @Fast Snail lol you are correct, it's localhost:3306/students. I hate typos, thank you very much sir, everything works now.

Answer (score 1):

I recently had a similar issue. My issue ended up being that the MySQL server version was 8.0.19, while flyway was using a 5.1.40 version of the java MySQL library.

Once I updated the MySQL library version to 8.0.19, my errors went away.

Answer (score 0):

This exception can have 4 causes:

1. User does not have privileges to connect to database.
2. MySQL service is not running.
3. Incorrect MySQL-Connector Jar.
4. Database URL is incorrect;.

Check above prerequisites before connecting to MySQL database.